# Why does Chrome not apply my second CSS class to my button when Safari does?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, smarty

Context: I am trying to simply have a button with two CSS classes attached to it. The first one is the general styling class I apply to all my buttons, .button, and the second is the specific styling I want for this particular button which I named .button3. I'm pretty new to CSS but I've tried many different formattings in calling the classes on the button element and declaring the classes in the CSS but nothing changes.

I am using smarty.

Applying class="button button2" works in chrome but not class="button button3"

The classes work fine in Safari.

Running the code in the SO code preview works fine in Chrome but not on my actual page.

These button classes are largely based on the W3Schools CSS buttons tutorial. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp

With these in mind I'm thinking this is a very specific issue that is out of my understanding when it comes to either CSS itself, Chrome, or just something very obvious I'm blind to after working on things for a while.

-Edit- Also, as the title suggests, it is only the second class (.button3) that is having issues. The first class (.button) is working in both Chrome and Safari.

Questions:

What is the difference in this situation between Chrome and Safari?

-and/or-

Why is it that class="button button2" works in Chrome but class="button button3" does not?

```css
.button {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*border-radius: 8px;*/
}
.button2 {
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    background-color: #f44336; /*red*/
    border: 1px solid #f44336;
    /*border-radius: 75%;*/
}
.button2:hover {
    background-color: whitesmoke; 
    color: black;
}
.button3 {
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    border: 1px solid lightseagreen;
}
.button3:hover {
    background-color: whitesmoke; 
    color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button3" type="submit" value="Submit"> Submit </button>
```

-Edit 2-
I have found the source of the issue. It seems to be that my CSS file running on my localhost ends abruptly before it reaches my `.button3` classes. I am looking for why this may be, but haven't found anything that would cause it as of yet.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? On Chrome 56 `.button3` is being applied

Comment: @ovokuro On my end only the general styling from `.button` is being applied. I don't get the proper border colors, font colors, or hover effects from `.button3` when using Chrome. It's helpful to know it's working for you though

Comment: @Von: Actually, it's not terribly helpful since presumably ovokuro is basing their observation on your runnable snippet, which you say works for you as well. If there's a way you can reproduce your issue somewhere that you can link to, I think that will go a long way.

Comment: @BoltClock yes I suppose that's true. Thinking about that it must be something outside of my code snippet that's affecting it then. I'll look into reproducing it but at the moment it is only on my localhost so I can't link the actual page.

Comment: @BoltClock I tried reproducing with no luck, but it seems I have found the source of the problem. I inspected the sources of my page when running on my localhost and looked into my CSS file through that. For some reason, my CSS file ends after `.button2:hover` class. Now I just need to figure out why this is. I'll update my question with the new information

Comment: @Von: Might be an older version of your stylesheet that's being held hostage by Chrome's cache. Might be an unwanted garbage control character (though I'd be surprised if Safari and Chrome handled it differently).

Comment: @BoltClock You are right! I cleared my cache on chrome and now it works perfectly. The reason it worked on safari was that I only opened safari after finding my changes weren't working on Chrome. I will accept this as the solution if you post it as an answer. (If that is proper etiquette. I'm new to SO, so please excuse me if it's not.)

Comment: Sounds like your question can be safely closed - we tend not to bother with answering if the question was resolved by clearing the cache. Not necessarily a bad thing though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean .
But you can use `!important` attribute in `CSS` properties that you want to force the browser to use them . 
Like this :

```css
.button3 {
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    background-color: lightseagreen !important; /* <-- That's the magic */
    border: 1px solid lightseagreen;
}
```

EDIT :
I see my friend's comment and see that `!important` attribute didn't work for him .
The other thing that we can do is to change the `classes` to `ids` .
Like :

```css
.button {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*border-radius: 8px;*/
}
#button2 {
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    background-color: #f44336; /*red*/
    border: 1px solid #f44336;
    /*border-radius: 75%;*/
}
#button2:hover {
    background-color: whitesmoke; 
    color: black;
}
#button3 {
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    border: 1px solid lightseagreen;
}
#button3:hover {
    background-color: whitesmoke; 
    color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<button id="button3" class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"> Submit </button>
```

It should works ...

Comment: If anyone do not get that just comment below .

Comment: I tried this but it does not work for me, I get the same result as before even when adding `!important' to certain elements.

Comment: It should works for everyone ;)

Comment: Thank you for all the input, these solutions may have helped if Chrome hadn't been holding on to an outdated file.

Comment: You can solve this problem by opening the `.html` file directly .<br />I mean don't use your localhost . Or you can clear your browsing data

Comment: And please vote up my answer

Comment: I voted you up from the start! However SO told me that while my vote would be counted, my own reputation was not high enough for it to be displayed as I am pretty new.